# Let $a$,$b$ be the roots of $x^2-6cx-7d=0$, and let $c$, $d$ be the roots of $x^2-6ax-7b=0$. Find $b+d$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let $a$,$b$ be the roots of the equation $x^{2}-6 c x-7 d=0$ and let $c$,$d$ be the roots of the equation $x^{2}-6ax-7 b=0$. $a,b,c,d$ are distinct. Find value of $b+d$.

Using the relation between roots and coefficients of an equation, I got $a+b+c+d=6(a+c)$, and hence getting $b+d= 5(a+c)$, but I don't know what to do next.

Also, $abcd= 49bd$, but I don't know how to use it here.

Comment: Note that in standard form ($x^2+ax+b$), $a = -\frac12 (r_1+r_2)$, so here $-6a = 2(c+d)$ for instance. So the first part of your solution should be $a+b+c+d= 3(a+c) \implies b+d = 2a + 2c$. Your last equation implies $ac=49$, so $b+d=2a+\frac{98}{a}$. I'm uncertain if that helps immediately though.

Comment: What's r1 and r2?

Comment: The two roots of the standard form monic quadratic. They're placeholders for whatever values you actually have. So $x^2+ax+b = (x-r_1)(x-r_2)$.

Comment: Bah, I have to correct myself. That $\frac12$ doesn't belong there after all, I was thinking of finding the roots themselves. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative approach:

From the original equations you have that:

- $[E_1:] ~ a + b = 6c \implies b = 6c - a.$
- $[E_2:] ~ c + d = 6a \implies d = 6a - c.$

Using the two results above, you also have, from the original equations that:

- $[E_3:] ~ 6ac - a^2 = ab = -7d = -7(6a - c) = 7c - 42a.$
- $[E_4:] ~ 6ac - c^2 = cd = -7b = -7(6c - a) = 7a - 42c.$

Subtracting $E_3 - E_4$ above gives

$(c-a)(c+a) = c^2 - a^2 = 7(c-a) + 42(c-a) = 49(c-a).$

This implies that $c+a = 49.$

Then, adding $E_1 + E_2$ gives

$(a + c) + (b + d) = 6(a + c) \implies (b + d) = 5(a + c) = 5 \times 49.$

Comment: With final solution $$a = \frac72 (7-3 \sqrt5), b = \frac{49}{2}(5+3 \sqrt 5), c = \frac72 (7+3 \sqrt5), d = \frac{49}{2}(5-3 \sqrt 5)$$ (And (a,b) interchangeable with (c,d), of course.)

Answer (score 3):

I like to work with a bit of generality whenever possible, so take the equations to be
$$x^2+pcx+qd=0 \qquad x^2+pax+qb=0$$
By Vieta's formula for the linear coefficients, we have a solvable linear system in $a$ and $c$:
$$
\left.\begin{align}
a+b=-pc \\ c+d=-pa
\end{align}\right\}\quad\to\quad a=\frac{b-dp}{p^2-1}\qquad c = \frac{d-bp}{p^2-1}\tag1$$
Then, by Vieta for the constant terms,
$$qd = ab=\frac{b-dp}{p^2-1}\,b \qquad\qquad qb=cd=\frac{d-bp}{p^2-1}\,d \tag2$$
Subtracting, and recalling the requirement that $b\neq d$,
$$q(d-b) = \frac{b^2-d^2}{p^2-1}=-\frac{(d-b) (b + d)}{p^2-1} \quad\to\quad b+d=-q(p^2-1) \tag3$$
For $p=-6$ and $q=-7$, the sum becomes $245$, in agreement with [@user2661923's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4458711/409).

Comment: +1 (also) : Very nice.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an example of a problem where "more Viete" isn't better.  Also, because of the way in which the two quadratic equations are "coupled", this is really a problem of two variables, rather than four.

You had established that $ \ 6c \ = \ a + b \ \ , \ \ -7d \ = \ ab \ \ , \ \ 6a \ = \ c + d \ \ , \ \ -7b \ = \ cd \ \ . \ $  We can "eliminate" two of the coefficients through
$$ a \ \ = \ \ \frac{c \ + \ d}{6} \ \ \ , \ \ \ b \ \ = \ \ -\frac{c \ · \ d}{7} \ \  \Rightarrow \ \ 6c \ \ = \ \ \frac{c \ + \ d}{6} \ - \ \frac{c \ · \ d}{7} $$ $$ \Rightarrow \ \ 252·c \ \ = \ \ 7c \ + \ 7d \ - \ 6·c ·d \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 245·c \ \ = \ \ d \ · \ (7 \ - \ 6c) \quad \quad \mathbf{[ \ 1 \ ]} $$
and
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ -7d \ \ = \ \ \left(\frac{c \ + \ d}{6} \right) \ · \ \left(\frac{c \ · \ d}{7} \right) \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 294·d \ \ = \ \ c ·d · (c \ + \ d) \ \ . \quad \quad \mathbf{[ \ 2 \ ]} $$
We can re-arrange equation $ \ \mathbf{2} \ $ as $ \ d · [ \ 294 - c·(c + d) \ ] \ = \ 0 \ \ . \ $  If $ \ d \ = \ 0 \ \ , \ $ then equation $ \ \mathbf{1} \ $ forces $ \ c \ = \ 0 \ \Rightarrow \ a \ , \ b \ = \ 0 \ \ , $ reducing *both* equations to a "trivial" case $ \ x^2 \ = \ 0 \ \ , $ which does not meet the requirement for all coefficients being *distinct*.  So we instead work with the factor $ \ 294 - c·(c + d) \   = \ 0 \ \ ;  \ $ inserting the result from equation $ \ \mathbf{1} \ $
produces
$$ c · \left( \ c \ + \ \left[\frac{245 \ · \ c}{7 \ - \ 6c} \ \right] \ \right) \ \ = \ \ 294 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{c^3 \ - \ 42c^2  \ - \  294c  \ +  \ 343 }{7 \ - \ 6c} \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ . $$

For this rational function equation, the value $ \ c \ = \ \frac76 \ $ is excluded (and does not solve the original problem), so we need to solve $ \ c^3 \ - \ 42c^2  \ - \  294c  \ +  \ 343 \ = \ 0 \ \ . $  Well, *this* looks unpleasant, until we notice that $ \ 343 \ = \ 7^3 \ \ . $  The Rule of Signs tells us that there are two or zero positive real and one negative real zero for this cubic polynomial, and the Rational Zeroes Theorem suggests "powers of $ \ 7 \ $ " as candidates.  Indeed, we find the factorization $ \ c^3 \ - \ 42c^2  \ - \  294c  \ +  \ 343 \ = \ (c + 7)·(c^2 - 49c + 49) \ = \  0 \ \ . $  We see that there are three real solutions
$$ \ c \ \ = \ \ -7 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ d \ \ = \ \ \frac{245 \ · \ (-7)}{7 \ - \ 6·(-7)} \ \    = \ \ \frac{-1715}{49} \ \ = \ \ -35 \ \ , $$
$$ \ c \ \ = \ \ \frac{49 \ \pm \ \sqrt{49^2 \ - \ 4·49}}{2} \ \ = \ \ \frac{49 \ \pm \ 7\sqrt{45}}{2} \ \ = \ \ \frac72·(7 \ \pm \ 3\sqrt{5}) $$ $$\Rightarrow \ \ d \ \ = \ \ \frac{245 \ · \ 7 · \ (7 \ \pm \ 3\sqrt{5})}{2 \ · \ [7 \ - \ 3·7·(7 \ \pm \ 3\sqrt{5})]} \ \ = \ \ -\frac{5 \ · \ 49 \ · \ 7 \ · \ (7 \ \pm \ 3\sqrt{5})}{2 \ · \ 7 \ · \  (20 \ \pm \ 9\sqrt{5})]} $$ $$ = \ \ \frac{49 }{2} · (5 \ \mp \ 3\sqrt{5}) \ \ . $$

If *all* we want to find is the sum $ \ b + d \ , $ our early relations yield
$ \ b +  d \   = \   d · \left(1  -  \frac{c }{7} \right) \ \ . $  For $ \ c \ = \ -7 \ \ , $ this gives us $ \ b + d \ = \ -35·(1 - [-1]) \ = \ -70 \ \ . $  The other two solutions give us
$$   b +  d \ \   = \ \  \frac{49 }{2} · (5 \ \mp \ 3\sqrt{5}) · \left[1  -  \frac{\frac72·(7 \ \pm \ 3\sqrt{5})}{7} \right] $$ $$ = \ \ \frac{49 }{2} · (5 \ \mp \ 3\sqrt{5}) · \frac72  · \left[ \frac{2 \ - \ 7 \ \mp \ 3\sqrt{5}}{7} \right]  $$
$$ = \ \ \frac{49 }{4} · (5 \ \mp \ 3\sqrt{5})  · ( - 5 \ \mp \ 3\sqrt{5}) \ \ = \ \  \frac{49 }{4} · 20 \ \ = \ \ 245 \ \ .  $$

What's up with the disparate result for $ \ b + d \ ? \ $  If we use the Viete relations again, we find $ \ 6a \ = \ (-7) + (-35) \ \Rightarrow \ a \ = \ -7 \ \ , \ \ -7b \ = \ (-7) · (-35) \ \Rightarrow \ b \ = \ -35 \ \ . $  So we have another "trivial" case in which *both* quadratic equations are $ \ x^2 + 42x + 245 \ = \ (x + 7)·(x + 35) \ = \ 0 \ \ . $  Here once again, the requirement that all of the coefficients be distinct is *not* satisfied.  Thus, $ \ \mathbf{245} \ $ is the sole answer for the problem.

If we go a bit farther to work out the details for the pair of quadratic equations, we obtain
$$ a \ \ = \ \ \frac{\frac72·(7 \ \pm \ 3\sqrt{5}) \ + \ \frac{49 }{2} · (5 \ \mp \ 3\sqrt{5})}{6} \ \ = \ \ \frac{49 \ · \ 6}{2 \ · \ 6} \ \mp \ \frac{42 \ · \ 3 \  \sqrt{5}}{2 \ · \ 6} \ \ = \ \ \frac72 \ · \ (7 \ \mp \ 3\sqrt{5}) \ \ \ , $$ $$ b \ \ = \ \ -\frac{\frac72·(7 \ \pm \ 3\sqrt{5}) \ · \ \frac{49 }{2} · (5 \ \mp \ 3\sqrt{5})}{7} \ \ = \ \ - \frac{49}{4} \ · \ (7 \ \pm \ 3\sqrt{5}) \ · \ (5 \ \mp \ 3\sqrt{5}) $$
$$ = \ \ \frac{49}{2} \ · \  (5 \ \pm \ 3\sqrt{5}) \ \ .$$

We note the "conjugate" relations between $ \ a \ $ and $ \ c \ $ and between $ \ b \ $ and $ \ d \ \ , $ making the four values distinct as required.  These also then have the "interchangeability" property remarked upon in **Eric Snyder**'s comment (and we confirm the values he lists).  It is immediately clear here that
$$   b + d \ \ = \ \ \frac{49}{2} \ · \  [ \ (5 \ \pm \ 3\sqrt{5}) + (5 \ \mp \ 3\sqrt{5}) \ ] \ \ = \ \ 245 $$

$$ = \ \ 5 \ · \left( \ \frac72 \ · \ \left[ \  (7 \ \mp \ 3\sqrt{5}) \ + \  (7 \ \pm \ 3\sqrt{5}) \ \right]  \ \right) \ \ = \ \ 5 \ ·  \  \frac{49}{2} \ \ = \ \ 5 ·(a + c) \ \ , $$

as you and **user2661923** observe.  [With a little work, we can verify that the pair of quadratic equations behave as specified.]

$$ \ \ $$

**ADDENDUM (6/11-12) --**

I was curious about how far this method could be generalized because a couple of points in the calculations seem to work out too "nicely" to be accidental.  (**Blue** has made a generalization for the argument based on the Viete relations.)

If we start from the pair of coupled quadratic equations $ \ x^2 + mcx + nd \ = \ 0 \ \ , $ with roots $ \ a \ , \ b \ $ and $ \ x^2 + pax + qb \ = \ 0 \ \ , $ with roots $ \ c \ , \ d \ \ , $ we now have

$$ a \ \ = \ \ -\frac{c \ + \ d}{p} \ \ \ , \ \ \ b \ \ = \ \ \frac{c \ · \ d}{q} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \  q·(mp \ - \ 1)·c \ \ = \ \ d \ · \ (q \ - \ pc) \quad \quad \mathbf{[ \ 1' \ ]} $$
$$ \text{and} \quad \Rightarrow \ \  d · [ \ npq + c·(c + d) \ ] \ = \ 0 \ \ . \quad \quad \mathbf{[ \ 2' \ ]} $$

Again, discarding the trivial $ \ d \ = \ 0 \ $ case, these two equations are combined into
$$ \frac{c^3 \ - \ mqc^2  \ + \  npqc  \ -  \ nq^2 }{q \ - \ pc} \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ . $$
We pass over once more $ \ c \ = \ \frac{q}{p} \ \ , $ which does not satisfy the conditions of the problem, leaving us to find the zeroes of the cubic polynomial in the numerator.  We find that this is a little *too* general, in that the solutions for $ \ c \ $ can lead to complex coefficients for the set of quadratic equations.  If we instead set $ \ m \ = \ p \ $ and $ \ n \ = \ q \ \ , $ which is then more in alignment with the original problem, the cubic equation becomes $ \ c^3  -  mnc^2   +   mn^2c  -  n^3  \  =  \ 0 \ \ , $ which factors as
$$ (c \ - \ n) \ · \ ( \ c^2 \ + \ n·[1 - m]·c \ + \ n^2 \ ) \ \ = \ \ 0 $$ $$ \Rightarrow \ \ c \ \ = \ \ n \ \ \ , \ \ \ \frac{n·(m - 1)}{2} \ \pm \ \frac{n \ · \ \sqrt{ (m + 1) \ · \ (m - 3)}}{2} \ \ . $$
(So the constant term $ \ -343 \ = \ (-7)^3 \ $ and the convenient solution of the cubic equation in the calculations above for the original problem were not just a pleasant happenstance.)

We "reject" the solution $ \ c \ = \ n \ \Rightarrow \ d \ = \ -n·(m+1) \ \ , \ \ a \ = \ -\frac{n - n·(m + 1)}{m} \ = \ n \ \ , $
$ b \ = \ \frac{n · (-n·[m + 1])}{n} \ = \ -n·(m+1) \ \ , $ as it makes the two quadratic equations identical, which is not permitted by the conditions of the problem.

Without running through the analogous calculations to find all of the coefficients and roots of the quadratic equations, we will work out the general result for the requested sum as
$$ b \ + \ d \ \ = \ \ d · \left( \frac{n \ + \ c}{n} \right) \ \ = \  \ \left[ \frac{n \ · \ (m^2 - 1) \ · \ c}{n \ - \ mc} \right] · \left( \frac{n \ + \ c}{n} \right) $$ $$ = \ \  (m^2 - 1)  · \left( \frac{n \ + \ c}{n \ - \ mc} \right) · c $$ $$ = \ \ (m^2 - 1)  · \left( \frac{n \ + \ \frac{n}{2}·[ \ (m - 1) \pm \sqrt{M} \ ]}{n \ - \ m·\frac{n}{2}·[ \ (m - 1) \pm \sqrt{M}] \ } \right) · \left(\frac{n}{2}·[ \ (m - 1) \pm \sqrt{M} \ ] \right) \ \ , $$
with $ \ M \ = \ (m + 1)·(m - 3) \ \ , $

$$ = \ \ \frac{n·(m^2 \ - \ 1)}{2}  · \left[ \frac{ (m + 1) \ \pm \ \sqrt{M}}{       (2 - m)·(m + 1) \ \mp \ m·\sqrt{M} } \right] · [ \ (m - 1) \ \pm \ \sqrt{M} \ ]  $$
$$ = \ \ \frac{n·(m^2 \ - \ 1)}{2}  · \left[ \frac{ (m^2 + M - 1) \ \pm \ 2m·\sqrt{M}}{ (2 - m)·(m + 1) \ \mp \ m·\sqrt{M} } \right] $$ $$ = \ \ \frac{n·(m^2 \ - \ 1)}{2}  · \left[ \frac{ 2·(m + 1)·(m - 2) \ \pm \ 2m·\sqrt{M}}{ (2 - m)·(m + 1) \ \mp \ m·\sqrt{M} } \right]   $$
$$ = \ \ \frac{n·(m^2 \ - \ 1)}{2}  \ · \ (-2) \ \ = \ \ n·(1 \ - \ m^2 ) \ \ , $$
in agreement with **Blue**'s general result.

This analysis exposes two other trivial cases when $ \ M \ = \ 0 \ $ for $ \ m \ = \ -1 \ \ \text{or} \ \ +3 \ \ : $

• $ \ \ \ c \  =  \ n \ \ , \ \ \frac{n·(-1 - 1)}{2} \ = \ -n \ \Rightarrow \ d \ = \ \frac{n·([-1]^2 - 1)·c}{n + c} \ = \ 0 \ \ $ and is undefined for $ \ c \ = \ -n \ \Rightarrow \ a \ = \ c + d \ = \ n \  , \ -n \ \ , \ \ b \ = \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ b + d \ = \ -n·([-1]^2 - 1) \ = \ 0 \ \ . $
Both quadratic equations are $ \ x^2 \ \pm \ nx \ = \ 0 \ \ . $

• $ \ \ \ c \  =  \ n \ \ , \ \ \frac{n·(3 - 1)}{2} \ = \ n \ \Rightarrow \ d \ = \ \frac{n·(3^2 - 1)·c}{n - 3c} \ = \ -4n \ \  \Rightarrow \ a \ = \ -\frac{c + d}{3} \ = \ -\frac{n \ - \ 4n}{3}  \ = \ n \ , \ \ b \ = \ -4n \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ b + d \ = \ -n·(3^2 - 1) \ = \ -8n \ \ . $
Both quadratic equations are $ \ x^2 \ + \ 3nx \ - \ 4n^2 = \ 0 \ \ . $

The requirement that all of the coefficients be distinct is violated in these two cases as well.